# Add button to Flash image flow component

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, coverflow, imageflow

Could anyone help me with adding a left and right button to this image flow component? At the moment it uses images to navigate left and right but I can seem to understand how to link a button with the action script?
I don't do much flash work so any help would be very much appreciated.

```
import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
xml=new XML();
xml.ignoreWhite=true;
xml.load("image_flow.xml"); // set the xml file for data
ActiveHeight=200;
InactiveHeight=70;
ActivePicture=1;
borderSize=2;
backgroundColor=0x666666;
backgroundOverColor=0x333333;
pictureSpacing=5;
ZoomSpeed=2;
MoveSpeed=3;
mirrorDistance=5;
autoFlow=false;
rand=true;
time=3000;

var titleFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
titleFormat.color=0xFFFFFF;
titleFormat.font="verdana";
titleFormat.size=12;


xml.onLoad = function(ok)
{
if (ok)
create_image_flow();
}

create_image_flow = function(){
this.createEmptyMovieClip("mask",this.getNextHighestDepth());
with(mask){
    beginFill(0x000000,100);
    lineTo(Stage.width,0);
    lineTo(Stage.width,Stage.height);
    lineTo(0,Stage.height);
    lineTo(0,0);
}


var pic:Object = new Object();
var picMirror:Object = new Object();

picMirror.onLoadInit = function(target:MovieClip){
    target.forceSmoothing = true;
    while (target._height>InactiveHeight){
        target._width-=target._width/100;
        target._height-=target._height/100;
    }
    height=target._height;
      while(target._height<=height){
            target._yscale-=1;
      }
    target.load=true;
    for (j=0;j<xml.firstChild.childNodes.length;j++)
     if (target==flow["object"+j].mirror.picture){
         target._y=flow["object"+j].background._height+mirrorDistance+target._height;
         with (flow["object"+j].mirror.background){
             beginFill(backgroundColor,100);
             lineTo(target._width+2*borderSize,0);
             lineTo(target._width+2*borderSize,target._height+2*borderSize);
             lineTo(0,target._height+2*borderSize);
             lineTo(0,0);
             _y=flow["object"+j].background._height+mirrorDistance-borderSize;
             _x=-borderSize;
         }
         with (flow["object"+j].mirror.backgroundOver){
             beginFill(backgroundOverColor,100);
             lineTo(target._width+2*borderSize,0);
             lineTo(target._width+2*borderSize,target._height+2*borderSize);
             lineTo(0,target._height+2*borderSize);
             lineTo(0,0);
             _y=flow["object"+j].background._height+mirrorDistance-borderSize;
             _x=-borderSize;
             _alpha=0;
         }
         with (flow["object"+j].mirrorMask){
             matrix = {matrixType:"box", x:0, y:-flow["object"+j].mirror.background._height/2, w:flow["object"+j].mirror.background._width, h:flow["object"+j].mirror.background._height, r:90/180*Math.PI};
             beginGradientFill(fillType, colors, alphas, ratios, matrix);
             lineTo(flow["object"+j].mirror.background._width,0);
             lineTo(flow["object"+j].mirror.background._width,flow["object"+j].mirror.background._height);
             lineTo(0,flow["object"+j].mirror.background._height);
             lineTo(0,0);
             _x=-borderSize;
             _y=flow["object"+j].mirror.background._y;
         }
         flow["object"+j].mirror.cacheAsBitmap=true;
         flow["object"+j].mirrorMask.cacheAsBitmap=true;
         flow["object"+j].mirror.setMask(flow["object"+j].mirrorMask);

     }

}

pic.onLoadInit = function(target:MovieClip){
    target.forceSmoothing = true;
    while (target._height>InactiveHeight){
        target._width-=target._width/100;
        target._height-=target._height/100;
    } 
    target.load=true;
    target.onRelease = function(){
        flow.title.text="";
        timer=undefined;
        for (j=0;j<xml.firstChild.childNodes.length;j++)
          if (target==flow["object"+j].picture){
              flow["object"+ActivePicture].swapDepths(ActivePicture+1);
              ActivePicture=j;
              flow["object"+ActivePicture].swapDepths(xml.firstChild.childNodes.length+1);
          }
    }
    target.onRollOver = function(){
        this.caption=true;
    }
    target.onRollOut = function(){
        this.caption=false;
    }
    target.onReleaseOutside = function(){
        this.caption=false;
    }

    for (j=0;j<xml.firstChild.childNodes.length;j++){
        if (target==flow["object"+j].picture){
            imagMirror.loadClip(xml.firstChild.childNodes[j].attributes.url,flow["object"+j].mirror.picture);
            with(flow["object"+j].background){
                beginFill(backgroundColor,100);
                lineTo(target._width+(2*borderSize),0);
                lineTo(target._width+(2*borderSize),target._height+(2*borderSize));
                lineTo(0,target._height+(2*borderSize));
                lineTo(0,0);
                _x=-borderSize;
                _y=-borderSize;
            }
            with(flow["object"+j].backgroundOver){
                beginFill(backgroundOverColor,100);
                lineTo(target._width+(2*borderSize),0);
                lineTo(target._width+(2*borderSize),target._height+(2*borderSize));
                lineTo(0,target._height+(2*borderSize));
                lineTo(0,0);
                _x=-borderSize;
                _y=-borderSize;
                _alpha=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
var imag:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
imag.addListener(pic);
var imagMirror:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
imagMirror.addListener(picMirror);

this.createEmptyMovieClip("flow",this.getNextHighestDepth());
flow.setMask(mask);
flow.createEmptyMovieClip("background",0);
with(flow.background){
    beginGradientFill(fillType, colorsBackground, alphasBackground, ratios, matrixBackground);
    lineTo(Stage.width,0);
    lineTo(Stage.width,Stage.height);
    lineTo(0,Stage.height);
    lineTo(0,0);
}
flow.createTextField("title",xml.firstChild.childNodes.length+2,0,0,0,0);
flow.title.autoSize="left";
flow.title.selectable=false;
for (i=0;i<xml.firstChild.childNodes.length;i++){
    if (i==ActivePicture)
    flow.createEmptyMovieClip("object"+i,xml.firstChild.childNodes.length+1);
    else
    flow.createEmptyMovieClip("object"+i,i+1);
    flow["object"+i].createEmptyMovieClip("background",1);
    flow["object"+i].createEmptyMovieClip("backgroundOver",2);
    flow["object"+i].createEmptyMovieClip("picture",3);
    flow["object"+i].createEmptyMovieClip("mirror",4);
    flow["object"+i].mirror.createEmptyMovieClip("background",1);
    flow["object"+i].mirror.createEmptyMovieClip("backgroundOver",2);
    flow["object"+i].mirror.createEmptyMovieClip("picture",3);
    flow["object"+i].createEmptyMovieClip("mirrorMask",5);
    imag.loadClip(xml.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.url,flow["object"+i].picture);
}

flow.onEnterFrame = function(){
    if ((getTimer()-timer>time)&&(autoFlow)){
        flow.title.text="";
        flow["object"+ActivePicture].swapDepths(ActivePicture+1);
        if (rand){
        ActivePicture=Math.round(Math.random()*(xml.firstChild.childNodes.length-1));
        if (ActivePicture<0)
          ActivePicture=0;
        }
        else{
            ActivePicture++;
            if (ActivePicture==xml.firstChild.childNodes.length)
             ActivePicture=0;
        }
        flow["object"+ActivePicture].swapDepths(xml.firstChild.childNodes.length+1);
        timer=undefined;
    }
    flow["object"+ActivePicture].x=(mask._width-flow["object"+ActivePicture]._width)/2;
    for (i=(ActivePicture+1);i<xml.firstChild.childNodes.length;i++)
       if (i==ActivePicture+1)
       flow["object"+i].x=flow["object"+(i-1)].x+flow["object"+(i-1)]._width+pictureSpacing-2*borderSize;
       else
        flow["object"+i].x=flow["object"+(i-1)].x+flow["object"+(i-1)]._width+pictureSpacing;

    for (i=(ActivePicture-1);i>=0;i--)
       flow["object"+i].x=flow["object"+(i+1)].x-flow["object"+i]._width-pictureSpacing;
    for (i=0;i<xml.firstChild.childNodes.length;i++){
        flow["object"+i].y=(mask._height-flow["object"+i]._height/2)/2;
        if (flow["object"+i].picture.load){
            if (i==ActivePicture){
               flow["object"+i].height=Math.round(2*ActiveHeight+(2*borderSize));
               flow["object"+i].filters=[];
            }
            else{
               flow["object"+i].height=Math.round(2*InactiveHeight+(2*borderSize));
               flow["object"+i].filters=[blurEffect];
            }
        }
        if (Math.round(flow["object"+i]._height)>flow["object"+i].height){
            flow["object"+i]._x+=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._width/200;
            flow["object"+i]._y+=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._height/200;
            ySize=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._height/200;
            xSize=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._width/200;
            flow["object"+i]._height-=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._height/100;
            flow["object"+i]._width-=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._width/100;
            if (flow["object"+i]._height<flow["object"+i].height){
                flow["object"+i]._x+=xSize;
                flow["object"+i]._y+=ySize;
                flow["object"+i]._height=flow["object"+i].height;
            }
        }
        if (Math.round(flow["object"+i]._height)<flow["object"+i].height){
            flow["object"+i]._x-=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._width/200;
            flow["object"+i]._y-=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._height/200;
            ySize=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._height/200;
            xSize=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._width/200;
            flow["object"+i]._height+=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._height/100;
            flow["object"+i]._width+=ZoomSpeed*flow["object"+i]._width/100;
            if (flow["object"+i]._height>flow["object"+i].height){
                flow["object"+i]._x+=xSize;
                flow["object"+i]._y+=ySize;
                flow["object"+i]._height=Math.round(flow["object"+i].height);
                flow.title.text=xml.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.title;
                flow.title.setTextFormat(titleFormat);
                flow.title._x=flow["object"+i]._x;
                flow.title._y=flow["object"+i]._y-flow.title._height-borderSize;
                timer=getTimer();
            }
        }
        if (flow["object"+i]._x<flow["object"+i].x)
            flow["object"+i]._x+=(flow["object"+i].x-flow["object"+i]._x)/MoveSpeed;
        if (flow["object"+i]._y<flow["object"+i].y)
            flow["object"+i]._y+=(flow["object"+i].y-flow["object"+i]._y)/MoveSpeed;
        if (flow["object"+i]._x>flow["object"+i].x)
            flow["object"+i]._x-=(flow["object"+i]._x-flow["object"+i].x)/MoveSpeed;
        if (flow["object"+i]._y>flow["object"+i].y)
            flow["object"+i]._y-=(flow["object"+i]._y-flow["object"+i].y)/MoveSpeed;
        if (flow["object"+i].picture.caption){
            flow["object"+i].filters=[];
            if (flow["object"+i].backgroundOver._alpha<100){
                flow["object"+i].mirror.backgroundOver._alpha+=5;
               flow["object"+i].backgroundOver._alpha+=5;
            }
        }
        else{
            if (flow["object"+i].backgroundOver._alpha>0){
                flow["object"+i].mirror.backgroundOver._alpha-=5;
              flow["object"+i].backgroundOver._alpha-=5;
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Seems like you would need to increment or decrement the ActivePicture variable on your button presses. Would you be able to post a working example in a zip somewhere and I'll have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two buttons to the stage.

Give them instance names of `btn1` and `btn2` (or any name of your choice)

Add the following code

```
btn1.onPress = function () {
    flow.title.text="";
    if (ActivePicture==xml.firstChild.childNodes.length-1){
        ActivePicture=0;
    }else{
        ActivePicture++;
    }
}

btn2.onPress = function () {
    flow.title.text="";
    if (ActivePicture<=0){
        ActivePicture=xml.firstChild.childNodes.length-1;
    }else{
        ActivePicture--;
    }

}
```

---

### What's Happening

Your buttons are incrementing or decrementing `ActivePicture` by 1 each time.  If `ActivePicture` goes above the number of pictures it changes to the first picture.  If `ActivePicture` goes below the number of pictures then it goes to the last picture.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks for all your comments and feedback. I'm sorry it has taken a while to respond - I didn't have my email notifications set up. I am just about to try out the code suggested so will let you know how I get on.
Oh and here is an example of the xml:

<galery>
<pic url="images/01.jpg" title="Petr Cech © Action Images"></pic>
</gallery>

Comment: I have just tried the code and it works but there seems to be a slight issue when it is at the beginning or end of the pictures. The btn2 makes the first picture shrink if clicked on the first image. Likewise, btn1 makes the last picture shrink. I have also noticed that the caption stays between moving the pictures rather than disappearing between movements.
I have adjusted the code but I'm not sure where to put it as there is not enough space in the comments box?!

Comment: I have found how to fix the caption bit. Just add flow.title.text="";

Comment: Just fixed it and checked the code again, you actually can scrape most of the code that I added out.  I made an edit to portray that.

Comment: Thanks @Engmadan - perfect all sorted. Thanks for all your help.